# Не могу разобраться в принципах работы event.stopPropagation() и event.stopImmediatePropagation()

Tags: javascript, html5

**к примеру вот код:**

```
star = document.getElementById("imageStar");
star.addEventListener('touchend', function (event) {
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
}, false);
star.addEventListener("touchend", function (event) {
alert("это не должно появиться!");}
);
```

**он работает** т.е выполняется сначала первый обработчик потом срабатывает

```
event.stopImmediatePropagation();
```

и второй обработчик не срабатывает, но если во втором обработчике заменить touchend на touchstart или click то
                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                 event.stopImmediatePropagation(); работать перестанет и будут выполнены все обработчики

Comment: Вдруг кто не знает https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/ Там про весь html, javascript и ещё кучу всего. Даже с рабочими примерами, которые тут же испытываются.

Comment: Если `touchend` заменить на `touchstart` это будут обработчики разных событий, а `stopImmediatePropagation` останавливает обработку только текущего события. Причём, очевидно, что `touchstart` случится раньше, так что пример вообще не о том.